How to Download Assets from air.inc API and Maintain Folder Structure for Large Data Sets?
I am working on a project where I need to download a smaller portion of data (around 10 GB) from the air.inc.
I am still in the planning phase and don't have much experience with such tasks. I would like to know how to approach it.
I need to keep track of the files that have already been downloaded ( database is 5 TB) to avoid redundant downloads. My main stack is Python.
